# How to update stock_quantity in python using woocommerce api

Tags: python, woocommerce

Trying to follow the api sample from http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?python#update-a-product-attribute, but it's not updating the stock_quantity.  I've confirmed that I have read/write access set for my api key.
I get the following error from the code below:
u'errors': [{u'message': u'No product data specified to edit product', u'code': u'woocommerce_api_missing_product_data'}]}
Any ideas?

```
import sys
import json
from woocommerce import API
wcapi = API(
    url="http://(myurl)",
    consumer_key="ck_<mykey>",
    consumer_secret="cs_<mysecret>",
    timeout=30
)
data = {
    "stock_quantity": 5
}

print(wcapi.put("products/18", data).json())
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok figured it out.  I was using the wrong version of the api documentation.  I should have been using v3.  The correct code is:

```
import sys
import json
from woocommerce import API
wcapi = API(
    url="http://(myurl)",
    consumer_key="ck_<mykey>",
    consumer_secret="cs_<mysecret>",
    timeout=30
)
data = {
    "product": {
        "stock_quantity": 5
    }
}
print(wcapi.put("products/18", data).json())
```

Answer (score 1):

In the newest version of the API I found wrapping the product info in the "product" dictionary is not needed:

```
import sys
import json
from woocommerce import API
wcapi = API(
    url="http://(myurl)",
    consumer_key="ck_<mykey>",
    consumer_secret="cs_<mysecret>",
    timeout=30
)
data = {
        "stock_quantity": 5
}
print(wcapi.put("products/18", data).json())
```